# How to combine Java plot code and Java serial code to read Arduino sensor value?

Tags: java, charts, serial-port, arduino, jfreechart

UPDATE: The code I am using can be found here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2108381/MyArduinoPlot.java
I hope this helps to understand my challenge. Thanks in advance for your time.

I would like to read sensor values from an Arduino and chart them using the Java library JFreeChart.

I found some code on the internet (see below) and now, I would like to combine the code for plotting a dynamic line chart and the code for reading in the Arduino values. Both codes do work separately, but I got stuck in combining them both.

The code for plotting a dynamic line chart is from here (plots random data):
http://dirtyhandsphp.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-draw-dynamic-line-or-timeseries.html

The code to read in Arduino values in Java is from here:
http://arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/Java

I assume (newbie in Java, though) that the relevant part is here:

```
/**
 * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
 */
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {
            int available = input.available();
            byte chunk[] = new byte[available];
            input.read(chunk, 0, available);

            // Displayed results are codepage dependent
            System.out.print(new String(chunk));

//              the code I tried

//              String MyValue = new String(chunk);
//              Double Value = Double.valueOf(MyValue); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
    // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
}
```

and here:

```
public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {


//      Original Code

    final double factor = 0.9 + 0.2*Math.random();
    this.lastValue = this.lastValue * factor;

    final Millisecond now = new Millisecond();
    this.series.add(new Millisecond(), this.lastValue);

    System.out.println("Current Time in Milliseconds = " + now.toString()+", Current Value : "+this.lastValue);

//        my code
//        this.series.add(new Millisecond(), Value);


}
```

How can I make the `public synchronized void serialEvent` return the sensor value and how can I add it to the `this.series.add` part?

I am a newbie in Java.

Any direct help or linkage to other websites/posts is greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513), a `javax.swing.Timer` periodically adds a new value to the `dataset` in the timer's `ActionListener`. You'll want to do it from outside. Here's an outline of how to proceed:

1. Move `dataset` and `newData` up to become [*instance variables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html):

   ```
   DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset;
   float[] newData = new float[1];
   ```
2. Add a method that appends your data to the chart's `dataset`:

   ```
   public synchronized void addData(byte[] chunk) {
       for (int i = 0; i < chunk.length; i++) {
           newData[0] = chunk[i];
           dataset.advanceTime();
           dataset.appendData(newData);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Invoke the method from `serialEvent()`:

   ```
   demo.addChunk(chunk);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @trashgod. Unfortunately, I do not fully understand it. Where do I need to put the "demo.addChunk(chunk)" and what to do with the "this.series.add(new Millisecond(), this.lastValue);" or the method "actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e)", respectively. Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: a) Item 3 says to call `addChunk()` from `serialEvent()`; b) I cited a different example that uses `advanceTime()`; c) no `Timer` means no `actionPerformed()`. BTW, I don't know what's in your data chunk.

Comment: Dear @trashgod, thanks again for your time and help. Unfortunately, I couldn't get back to this issue for a while and now, I could not get it to work. [Here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2108381/MyArduinoPlot.java), is the link to my java file which contains all of the code. Would be great if someone got the time and skills to help me out. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What happens when you call `addData()` from `serialEvent()`?

Comment: I am not sure where to make this call, @trashgod. I tried various ways but to no avail. Sorry, I am a newbie. I still have the "actionPerformed" in my code. Hope that is ok. Thanks again for helping me out.

Comment: I don't have your hardware, so I can't test/debug your code. You might want to update your question to include the link to your code.