# DynamicTimeSeriesCollection and Serial communications

Tags: java, dynamic, serial-port, time-series, jfreechart

I am using DynamicTimeSeriesCollection to plot measurements from serial port into my graph.
I want to use the code that I have found in another post.

I want to achieve something like this:
[Using JFreeChart to display recent changes in a time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852/using-jfreechart-to-display-recent-changes-in-a-time-series/5048863#5048863)

Code from another post that I have found:

[How to combine Java plot code and Java serial code to read Arduino sensor value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077692/how-to-combine-java-plot-code-and-java-serial-code-to-read-arduino-sensor-value)

```
1. Move dataset and newData up to become instance variables:

DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset;
float[] newData = new float[1];

2. Add a method that appends your data to the chart's dataset:

public synchronized void addData(byte[] chunk) {
    for (int i = 0; i < chunk.length; i++) {
        newData[0] = chunk[i];
        dataset.advanceTime();
        dataset.appendData(newData);
    }
}

3. Invoke the method from serialEvent():

demo.addChunk(chunk);
```

Here is my Serial Event method within SerialCommunication class:

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try
        {
            Date d = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            String datetime = dt.format(d);
            String inputLine = input.readLine();

            String[] measurements = inputLine.split(",");
            double humidity = Double.parseDouble(measurements[0]);
            double temp = Double.parseDouble(measurements[1]);
            double ldr = Double.parseDouble(measurements[2]);
            humidityList.add(humidity);
            tempList.add(temp);
            ldrList.add(ldr);

            System.out.println(datetime+" > "+inputLine);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

And ArrayList in Serial Communication class:

```
private ArrayList<Double> humidityList = new ArrayList<Double>();
private ArrayList<Double> tempList = new ArrayList<Double>();
private ArrayList<Double> ldrList = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Here is how I did declare ArrayList in GUI class:

```
private static ArrayList<Double> m1;
private static ArrayList<Double> m2;
private static ArrayList<Double> m3;


public GUI(final String title,ArrayList<Double> humidity,ArrayList<Double> temp,ArrayList<Double> ldr) 
{

super(title);
m1 = humidity;
m2 = temp;
m3 = ldr;
```

I did try to modify code that I have found with my measurements but no luck. Any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) is the best way to handle this.

- Create a class `Measurement` containing three `Double` attributes.
- Extend `SwingWorker<Measurement, Measurement>`
- In your implementation of `doInBackground()`, `publish()` each `Measurement` as it arrives .
- In your implementation of `process()`, update the chart's dataset, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513).